# New Record Does Not Show In ASP.net Datagrid Inside Updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, webforms, linqdatasource

I have an asp.net webpage that contain a gridview with edit, select and delete enabled, and a detailview for inserting new record. Each control is placed inside a asp.net ajax extension control-updatepanel. And the two controls are bonded to the same datasource which is LinqDataSource.

After new record was inserted nothing display in the gridview until user refresh the page.
Did I miss something? Can anyone help?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<fieldset>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">       
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="TermLinqDataSource" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
        DataKeyNames="TermID">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField 
                ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowIndex" HeaderText="RowIndex" 
                InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="RowIndex" Visible="False" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TermID" HeaderText="Term" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="TermID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Start Date" 
                SortExpression="StartDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="End Date" 
                SortExpression="EndDate" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />               
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />  
        </Columns>                        
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <br />
    <h4>Add New Term:</h4>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DetailsView ID="addNewTerm" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="TermID" 
            DataSourceID="TermLinqDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert">
            <FieldHeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" />
            <Fields>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TermID" HeaderText="Term:" SortExpression="TermID" 
                    ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartDate" HeaderText="Start Date:" 
                    SortExpression="StartDate" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EndDate" HeaderText="End Date:" 
                    SortExpression="EndDate" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DetailsView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="TermLinqDataSource" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="CETMSClient.RegistraDCsDataContext" EnableDelete="True" 
        EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" TableName="Terms" 
        OrderBy="RowIndex desc" >
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Comment: do you have any code behind code written?

Comment: What if we use Only One Update panel for both GridView & DetailsView?

Comment: Still the same result, new record not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to bind gridview again after insertion.
Visit [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.iteminserted.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.iteminserted.aspx)

Comment: Throw an example in here just in case microsoft changes the link. Its happened in the past.

Comment: Ok, call DataBind() method of the DataGrid on an ItemInserted event handler of DetailView or LinqDataSource makes it work. Thanks a lot.